# Is it possible to create a nested for...of loop in the same way as the traditional for loop below?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, data-structures

I'm trying to replicate this selection sort for loop using a for... of loop. I've worked on transitioning it for awhile now, however, nothing that I've tried has worked. Is this possible?

Array set:

```
var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Carrot", "Guava", "Orange"];
```

Traditional for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < fruits; i++) {
  let outerItem = fruits[i];
  for (var j = i + 1; j < fruits.length; j++) {
    let innerItem = fruits[j];
    if (innerItem == outerItem) {
      innerItem.length > outerItem.length ? fruits.splice(fruits.indexOf(outerItem), 1) :
        fruits.splice(fruits.indexOf(innerItem), 1);
    }
  }
}
```

for...of loop

```
for(let  outerItem of fruits)
{
    for(let innerItem of fruits)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice that the inner loop of the first version starts from `i+1`, it doesn't loop over the entire `fruits` array.

Comment: `i < fruits` should be `i < fruits.length`

Comment: You can but it will start with index 0. In traditional for loop you can define where you want to start the loop

Comment: @Barmar nice catch. My mistake there.

Comment: @Inder So it isn't possible then, unless I do splicing to ensure the second loops doesn't start off in the same position?

Comment: yes, you'll have to splice the array.
If you want to run the loop at index 1, then you will have to splice the array from index 1. Thats why I think traditional for loop is better

Comment: There's this condition check: `if (innerItem == outerItem)` and then if that is `truthy` (ie, innerItem and outerItem matched), we have another `innerItem.length > outerItem.length`. So, if both items are equal (`==`) does one ever expect `length` of one to be greater than the other, given that the only options that these items can be are strings (fruit names, from the array, which does not have any duplicates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fast replicate an array, use slice: `const sliced = fruits.slice();`

The below shows the solution of `Traditional for loop` and `for...of loop` on a given array `var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Carrot", "Guava", "Orange"];`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        const writeln = (text = '') => document.writeln(text + '<br/>');
    </script>
    <script>
        var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Carrot", "Guava", "Orange"];

        writeln(fruits);

        writeln();
        writeln('Slice');
        const sliced = fruits.slice();
        writeln(sliced);    

        writeln();
        writeln('Traditional for loop');    
        const copy = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
            copy.push(fruits[i]);
        }
        writeln(copy);

        writeln();
        writeln('for...of loop');
        const copy1 = [];
        for (const value of fruits) {
            copy1.push(value);
        }
        writeln(copy1);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```